# Linear system of inequalities.

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations

Given linear system:

$$4+\delta_1-\delta_2\ge 0 \\ 2-\delta_1+\delta_2 \ge 0 \\ 1+\delta_1-\delta_2+\delta_3 \ge 0$$

How from there it follows that $\delta_2=\delta_3 = 0$ and $\delta_1\neq0$?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't, try $$\delta_1=\delta_2=\delta_3=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Defining $\delta_{12} = \delta_1-\delta_2$:

$$
\begin{matrix}
4+\delta_{12}\ge 0           && \rightarrow && \delta_{12}\ge -4\\
2-\delta_{12} \ge 0          && \rightarrow && \delta_{12} \le 2\\
1+\delta_{12}+\delta_3 \ge 0 && \rightarrow && \delta_3 \ge -\delta_{12} -1\\
\end{matrix}$$

So the solution domain in the $\delta_{12} \, \text{x} \, \delta_3$ plane is something like:

[image]

Now, focusing on the $\delta_{1} \, \text{x} \, \delta_{2}$ plane:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\delta_{12}\ge -4 && \rightarrow && \delta_{2} \le \delta_{1} + 4\\
\delta_{12} \le 2 && \rightarrow && \delta_{2} \ge \delta_{1} - 2\\
\end{matrix}$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The feasible set is something prismatic ...

[image]